# Will topic based searches work after freebase is deprecated

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Freebase will be deprecated starting [Tuesday, March 31st](https://plus.google.com/109936836907132434202/posts/3aYFVNf92A1), what does this mean for topic based searches with the youtube api? Will these queries still work?

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relevanceLanguage=en&topicId=%2Fm%2F04qf57&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be unaffected since [Google Knowledge Graph API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/), which is the replacement of Freebase, is able to search by `topicId` too.

Do not quote me on this one though as there's really no documented change notes on the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/searching_by_topic)

Also, some SO posts that contains discussions regarding the possible impact and alternatives(as of the moment) to the use of Youtube Data API and `topicIds` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999995/youtube-api-v3-topicid-recovery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636215/how-can-i-query-wikidata-with-a-freebase-id-from-a-youtube-video)